# Should Android listView adapter have api calls

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-adapter, android-mvp

Hi I have a adapter which displays the list of items and all the functions related to `setItems`, `getCount`, `notifyDataSetChanged`.

adapter also has calls to api's through use cases.

Structure is

Adapter -> UseCase -> Repository -> apiLayer

I am aware that fragemnts and activities should not contains calls to api (usecases in my instance).

So should adapter's have api calls (usecases in my instance)

Thanks
R

Comment: It's possible, though when configuration changes happens (like device rotation) your Activity/Fragment gets recreated (and so the Adapter) and you loose your UI state. You should consider having a ViewModel, having the UseCase etc. From the Activity/Fragment you can then observe changes of the ViewModel and update the Adapter. This way configuration changes will not lead to data loss / re-fetching data.

Comment: so it is not ideal to hav usescases in adapter but its not a bad idea either?

Comment: You can definetely do it, if you can live with the downsides. Though I would not recomend it. Having a ViewModel updating the Adapter (via Activity) is in my opinion a better separation of concern. For me the adapter is just there to connect the data with your view. It should not do anyhing more. So it's more a question of good design. And think of testability, can you easily unit test the adapter? Having it in a viewModel makes testing much easier.

Comment: yes I completely agree with you on that.

Comment: so if it is a MVP patter, all the calls should be on the presenter layer and adapter talks to the presenter layer

Comment: Kind of, or better, only the Activity/Fragment talks to the presenter: `presenter.fetchData()` and then updates the adapter with that data. So the adapter does not know anything else than the data and the view. Having less dependencies to your adapter (less knowledge) will make it more robust to changes etc.

Comment: You are welcome. I just posted an answer summarizing my comments, incl little code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but from a software design point of view I would not recommend it.

The `Adapter`'s responsibility is to connect your `Data` with the `View` and make it available to the `ListView`/`RecyclerView`. The Adapter should not have any other dependency (knowledge). This will also make it more robust to changes.

So you should consider that only the Activity/Fragment talks to your Presenter and delegates the results from the Presenter to the Adapter.
This will also make (unit) testing (of the Presenter) more easier.

```kotlin
class YourActivity: Activity() {
  private val presenter: YourPresenter = // ...

  override fun onCreate() {
    val adapter: YourAdapter = YourAdapter()
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)

    val data = presenter.getData()
    adapter.submit(data)
  }
}

class YourPresenter(private val useCase: UseCase : Presenter() {
  fun getData(): List<Data> {
    return useCase.fetchData()  
  }
}
```